# How to check a file is a SSL certificate or a regular file using java?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I need to scan a directory and list all the certificates and their expiry dates. The directory can have non-certificate files.

Comment: Consider trying to interpret each file as if it were a certificate and if it isn't, it should fail a check for validity or throw an exception even sooner (e.g. formatting). This comment assumes the use of some built-in Java class(es), which I'm probably not familiar with.)

Comment: Forget about Java first. Do you have criteria that let you decide if a file is a SSL certificate or not?

Comment: I am expecting them to be PEM private key files or p12 keystores or jks keystores. I was thinking of trying to load or create certificate with the file and if it throws error then treat them as non-certificate files. But for keystores, the error could be with password too so need to differentiate with password error vs non-certificate error.

Comment: @user1253229: I think you should keep different limited-access directories for each.

Comment: Yes Ray. That would be our next step once we clean up the existing folders of with back up copies of expired and duplicate certificates.

Comment: Don't understand why my question is voted as not clear or research is not done. Been trying to find an answer since yesterday in google.

Comment: @user1253229: I might be stating the obvious here, but the contents of the question itself don't show what research you may or may not have done, or what you may or may not have tried (i.e. code you wrote that didn't work as you intended, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comment into an actual response.

Consider trying to interpret each file as if it were a certificate. If it isn't, then it should fail a check for validity and/or throw an exception even sooner than that (e.g. due to bad formatting).

If all the pertinent checks pass for the file currently under evaluation, then you should have a valid certificate.

Note that I'm assuming the use of any built-in Java class(es) designed for this purpose. If you're trying to use your own custom-developed classes, then my suggestion is: *don't*.

Security is easier to screw up than it is to do right. Use Java built-ins or something from developers with a good track-record in security.

A better thing to do would be to just limit the directory to contain certificates only. There's probably no good reason to mix them up like that.